# Quartz Scheduler Administration Page: Information about misfired triggers

Tags: quartz-scheduler, monitoring

We have a Java application (ESB) that uses quartz 2.2.1 and we use it to schedule hundreds of user jobs.

I want to build monitoring page (or scheduler administration page) in my application for our users so that they can see if quartz scheduler is running fine or there is any issue in this component.

Does quartz provides any monitoring API for this purpose? Can anyone please tell us what all data points should we show in this monitoring (or administration) page based on your experience? Some of the points that I can think of:

1. Scheduler Status (Running | Paused | Shutdown).
2. Number of jobs running with "Previous Fire Time" and "Next FireTime" information.
3. Thread pool implementation and its size.
4. JDBCJobStore configuration details.

Is there a way to show the information about triggers that were misfired? I don't see any API that provides me information about misfired triggers. Can anyone tell me how to get this information from scheduler?

Any help in this regard shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named here many different issues

Scheduler Status(1) :

```
Scheduler sched =...
sched.isInStandbyMode();
sched.isStarted();
sched.isShutdown();
```

Number of jobs running with...(2) see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-jobs-in-the-quartz-scheduler/)

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

   for (String groupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames()) {

     for (JobKey jobKey : scheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {

      String jobName = jobKey.getName();
      String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();

      //get job's trigger
      List<Trigger> triggers = (List<Trigger>) scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
      Date nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime(); 

        System.out.println("[jobName] : " + jobName + " [groupName] : "
            + jobGroup + " - " + nextFireTime);

      }

    }
```

Thread pool implementation and its size.(3)

```
Scheduler sched =...
sched.getMetaData().getThreadPoolClass()
sched.getMetaData().getThreadPoolSize()
```

Regarding "triggers that were misfired", you can use [listeners](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07.html), specifically [TriggerListener.html#triggerMisfired](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html#triggerMisfired(org.quartz.Trigger)) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Does TriggerListener.html#triggerMisfired gets invoked even if trigger is set to ignore the misfire instruction?

Comment: I've have tried that, but from the code of Quartz it seems that for `RAMJobStore` it won't be invoked for `MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY`, but for `JDBCJobStore` which is your case it seems it will get invoked. Please update in case it won't work.

Comment: Also notice there is this [Logging Trigger History Plugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigPlugins.html) which might be useful for your monitoring purposes.