# Is there a way to preserve fired triggers in quarts (java)?

Tags: java, scala, triggers, quartz-scheduler

We are using quartz as our main scheduler in our app.
The way it works now, it removes the triggers and jobs that been successfully executed. However, for debugging and tracking purposes we need to preserve that information.

Now, it is easy to do it for the jobs by setting `storeDurably` to `true`. Is there a way to achieve the same for triggers?

Thanks.

Comment: But when you have the Job that is durable why you want also the trigger durable? When you want to execute the job you run the code which create the trigger. Your trigger is durable because it is in your code and is related to a durable job. Is it not more simple?

Comment: Because I want to know the exact time when it was fired and what was the status of the system at that moment.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the relation between the time when the trigger was fired and its durability. Which type of trigger are you using? Simple or Cron?

Comment: Both. all I want to get is sort of audit trail of fired triggers.

Comment: Ah ok so you want to query triggers tables to check when it was executed?

Comment: also, when and, ideally, on what machine.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to base such an audit on the internals of quartz. Maybe you have to create a sort of "proxy" for simple and cron triggers to log the information that you need.

Comment: Yah, I am starting to think about simple log of these events.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you only need to preserve logging information.

You can use [Logging Trigger History Plugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigPlugins.html) to log what you need. You can see some samples [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-plugins-hidden.html)(also for `LoggingJobHistoryPlugin`).
If you need more customized behavior, you can use [Trigger Listeners](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07.html) in which you will implement the exact logging you want in [TriggerListener#triggerFired](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html#triggerFired(org.quartz.Trigger,%20org.quartz.JobExecutionContext)) and/or [TriggerListener#triggerComplete](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html#triggerComplete(org.quartz.Trigger,%20org.quartz.JobExecutionContext,%20org.quartz.Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction)).

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719868/3883957) about overall monitoring of quartz.